# How to read 2 gb file from one folder in S3 bucket and process it using spring batch, Now Im getting out of memory issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Getting heap memory issue since Im trying to hold the entire 2gb file in memory

Please help on reading the data in chunks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Next time please provide some code for how you get access to the S3 object.

But as a guess I suppose you are obtaining a [S3ObjectInputStream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectInputStream.html) and then using a function to read all the bytes in a `byte[]` in one go and then your get the memory exception.

The general technique to this problem is to open the input stream and the output stream at the same time and read a "buffer" of bytes at a time.

This problem has been solved many times in utilities such as Apache's IO Utils, read about `copyLarge` here https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html